# keep aspect ratio of background image (android)

Tags: android, xml

I have a background image which should be scaled on the height, but keep its aspect ratio. I tried it with this code:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" />
```

This works on phones in portrait mode, but when I test it on a tablet (default landscape), it scales the width and cuts the image on top and bottom. Is this because of the xml code or because of the landscape?

Comment: have you tried removing `android:scaleType="centerCrop"`

Comment: yes, then it doesnt work on phones in potrait mode

Comment: Could you show us some screens?

Comment: i used this bg for exaple: http://rivello.net/img/bg.jpg
phone: http://abload.de/img/1t9kx7.png
tablet: http://abload.de/img/3vbjo6.png

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Because it's working as intended on my tablet. the image will always be cut unless you display white stripes on top/bottom or left/right

Comment: i imagined it like this: http://abload.de/img/bgjdi4m.jpg it should only cut the sides, but in the avd tablet emulator it cuts top and bottom.

Comment: Here is a print of my tablet. https://www.dropbox.com/s/prnj8gutcgz1ddl/Captura%20de%20tela%202014-09-10%2012.03.32.png As you can see. Nothing cut.

Comment: on your tablet, it also cuts the top and bottom of the image

Comment: But that's the actionbar and the system bar. That's what is supposed to happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60963/discussion-between-pedro-oliveira-and-vtni).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_image"/> 

    <!-- Your other views -->

</RelativeLayout>
```